# Loop through SQL Data in Powershell based on key value

Tags: sql, powershell

I have a query that is returning a couple of sample rows like below assigned to a variable $rows

```
Name    Status    IsCurrent
------  ------    ---------
DBNODE1 dbdone         1
dbnode2 dbdone         0
```

and am writing this for loop to assign values based on the above data

```
foreach($data in $rows){
    if ($data.IsCurrent = 1) {
        $Prim = $data.Name
    }
    else { $Sec = $data.Name }
}
```

Tried another variation of it as well:

```
foreach($data in $rows){
    if ($data.IsCurrent = 1) {
        $Prim = $data.Name
    }
    elseif ($data.IsCurrent = 0){ 
        $Sec = $data.Name 
    }
}

Write-Host $Prim (returns dbnode02 instead of DBNODE1)
Write-Host $Sec (returns empty)
```

but no matter what I do, the values are not being assigned correctly to the variables.

From debugging, I see that the for loop is not going into the else/elseif stmt and further more when I print $rows data after running the script, the IsCurrent column updates to both 0's or 1's depending on what I do.

Am I missing something here? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `=` is for assignment, if you're looking for equality then you need to use `-eq`. `$data.IsCurrent -eq 1`

Comment: ah yeah, I overlooked that one, thank you!